# Add bar lines with the beats below each measure

Tags: theory, sheet-music, meter

[image: Two exercises with time signature given, bar lines to be added]

Hello, I need to complete these exercises. I need to add bar lines and label the beats.

Comment: Hi Mary Jane. Welcome to the site. We won't do homework assignments, but if you explain what you don't understand, we can help clarify.

Comment: I don't understand 3/16 like the counts don't add for me, I thought it was per note example a whole note is 4 counts so i have to put the bar there, but it seems that it is per spaces 1 2 3 4... that's why its confusing, example on the second photograph #1 the quaver is count as 1 or count as 3 spaces?

Comment: We certainly won't do your homework for you, but will explain **how** to do it. Which is probably what teacher should have already done...

Answer (score 5):

I'll do just a tiny bit of it for you.   Get the idea?    Don't fall into the trap of thinking a quarter note is always a beat!  You're being asked to understand what value of note IS a beat in the various time signatures.

[image]

Comment: When I saw an answer I thought: "Once again someone answered am homework question...". But I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling a crotchet a *quarter note* is part of the clue to an answer!

When the bottom number **is** 4, then yes, a beat or a count will be how many of those are used (top number) in the bar.

However, a lot of those exercises have a different number there, so '4' becomes totally irrelevant.

Use the top and bottom numbers to formulate what constitutes one bar. For example, 3/8 means there are 3 eighth notes per bar; 4/8 means there are 4 eighth (quaver) notes in a bar; and yes, 3/4 means there are 3 crotchets (quarter notes) per bar.

That bottom number, combined with counting the top, will reveal where the beats come - not always where there are crotchets (except in x/4 time).

Or their equivalent rests, when you get to that part of the test paper!

Comment: No need to go into Compound Time now.  Just be aware this is a partial explanation.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - absolutely - trying to go to the OP's level.